# How to brew beer at home from 0% beer, yeast and sugar?

Tags: specialty-beers

I have a lot of 0% beer at home and I wanna make them 8%-18% alcohol. I've been said that if I add yeast and sugar to 0% beer, it will become alcoholic beer. Now I need proportion of yeast and sugar for 1 Liter beer and the process to make it happen?

Comment: I didn't understand.  You want to make your own alcohol?  Or do you want to know what kind of existing alcohol to add to your 0% beer?

Comment: I want my beer have natural alcohol and be not 0%

Comment: So, you want it to have the alcohol of a "real" beer, but all the crappy flavor of a NA beer.  Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Ethanol is "natural" in the sense that it comes from fermentation. Neutral spirits are created through distillation to concentrate the alcohol. In theory you can combine sugar, water, yeast to make something that is kind of neutral in flavor, but that will only get you to about 16-20% alcohol. So you would have to dilute the 0% beer with this 16% brew and therefore dilute the flavors of the original beer. Far more effective, would be to buy some vodka and dump that into your beer (Unless you are in a country where you can't buy it, which is what I suspect). Look up "Sugar Wine" recipes like this [Sugar Wine](http://homemade-alcohol-college.blogspot.com/2008/03/sugar-wine.html) recipe.

Comment: If you want to concentrate this "sugar wine" even more, freeze it and you can easily double the strength by pouring out the non frozen alcohol and leaving the frozen water behind.